# Крым и Кремль

Tags: этимология, семантика

Есть ли этимологическая/семантическая связь между наименованиями Крым и Кремль?

Answer (score 9):

Оказывается, кто-то всерьез отнесся. Ну попробую всерьез и ответить.
Кремль - слово, ничего общего с тюркским не имеющее.
Во-первых, древность. Тюркские заимствования пришли много позже.
Во-вторых, "крепость" - у кремля значение вторичное. Посмотрите, какое богатство родственных слов в славянских языках:

> **Кремль**
>   кремль род. п. -мля́ "крепость внутри города", др.-русск. кремль, I Соф. летоп. под 1445 г.; Мунехин (1493 г.), стр. 216; библия 1499 г. и др. (Срезн. I, 1320), также крем(ь)никъ, 1331 г. (Забелин, Энц. Слов. 38, 930). Сюда же: кремь м. "часть засеки, где растет лучший строевой лес", кремлёвый "крепкий, прочный" (о строительном лесе), кремлёвая сосна́ "сосна на опушке леса (на сухой почве)", тоб. (ЖСт., 1899, вып. 4, стр. 497). Родственно кре́мень и крома́ (см.), согласно Миклошичу (Мi. ЕW 137), Соболевскому (РФВ 70, 86 и сл.). Из *кремльнъ произошло нем. Kremelin (Майерберг), франц. Cremlin; см. Соболевский, там же. Неприемлемо фонетически объяснение из кыпч. kärmän "крепость", монг. kerem, калм. kerɨ̥̄, вопреки Рамстедту (KWb. 227), Рясянену (FUF Anz. 24, 49). •• [Маловероятна этимология Махека (SPFFBU, 2, 1953, стр. 127 и сл.); кремль из krе̌р-, кре́пкий. – Т.]
>   *Этимологический словарь русского языка. — М.: Прогресс М. Р. Фасмер 1964—1973*

Кырым же на турецком (он же - крымско-татарский) вал, стена. Значения, далекие от славянских. К тому же это, насколько понимаю, не общепринятая версия происхождения топонима.

Нет, как хотите, но политика опять вмешивается в лингвистику. Иначе объяснить подобное толкование просто отказываюсь.

Answer (score 0):

Э.М.Мурзаев в своем Словаре народных географических терминов приводит подробные данные :

> **КЕРМАН, КЕРМЕН** - крепость, город (тюрк.). Отмечено В. В. Радловым [1898, 2] в чагат. яз. Чуваш. карман, татар. кирмен, мар. карман - "крепость". Др.-рус. керемень - "укрепление". Интересно, что Б. А. Серебренников [Этимология, 1968. М., 1971] в коми слове кар - "город" видит усеченное камско-булгарское карман - "крепость". ◊ Глубокий след в топонимии южных областей СССР: Инкерман - пещерный город, славящийся добычей белого камня, в Крымской обл.; Кременчуг и нп Кременчугский в Полтавской обл.; гор. Белгород-Днестровский, в прошлом Аккерман (белая крепость), что можно сравнить с византийским Левкополь или молд. Четатя-Альбэ с тем же смыслом; г. Керман в Баксанском ущелье на Северном Кавказе; Кермен в Болгарии на запад от Ямбола; Керман и Керманшах в Иране. См. кар2, хэрэм.
>
> **ХЭРЭМ** - крепость, крепостной вал,
> крепостная стена (бур., монг.). Письмен, монг.
> kеrem - то же. Ср. солонское хэрэм - "городская
> стена"; негидальское кэjэн из керен -
> "изгородь", "забор", "ограда"; ульчс. кэрэ(н) -
> "ограда", "забор", "стойло", "граница"; маньч.
> кэрэму - "вал", "крепостная стена" [ТМС, 1975,
> 1]. Сюда же - тув. херим - "лагерь", "вал",
> "ограждение". Алт. корум - "защита". Можно
> ли указать на др.-тюрк. qirim, qarim - "яма",
> "ров", qaram - "ров"? Ср. крым.-тат. кермен ,
> кäрмäн - "крепость". В отчетах русских
> путешественников по Центральной Азии часто
> приводится форма хырма - "укрепленный
> поселок"; "ставка должностного лица". Иван
> Петлин, первый русский посланец в Китае,
> **описал Великую Китайскую стену под именем
> "Китайский Крым"**. ◊ Цаган-Хэрэм - монг.
> название Великой Китайской стены; ур. Хырым
> в Восточной Монголии; старая крепостца
> караул Кырмытын-Хорол у подножия Большого
> Хингана. Длинный, на многие километры
> земляной вал в Восточной Монголии - Хэрым-
> Дзам, т. е. крепостная дорога. Сюда же п-ов
> Крым - название, появившееся только с конца
> XV в.; первоначально нп Старый Крым -
> название, сменившее греч. Тавриду [Э. М.
> Мурзаев. Изв. РГО, 1948, 80, 3]. М. Фасмер
> [1967, 2] отвергает по фонетическим
> соображениям объяснение названия кремль из
> кипчакского kärmän - "крепость"; монг. kerem,
> калм. kerm, о чем писали Г. Рамстедт и М.
> Рясянен. Следует при этом учесть
> исторические данные. Слово кремль вошло в
> русскую речь сравнительно поздно. Первые
> упоминания относятся к середине XV в., т. е. к
> концу ордынской эпохи. См. керман, кремль.

Модель древней монгольской столицы - Каракорума :
[image: Каракорум]
План московского Кремля :
[image: Кремль]

Существует мнение, что в подражание Каракоруму московский белокаменный Кремль называли - **Ак-Корум**. Неофициальным титулом московского государя на Востоке было наименование "белый царь".
Следует добавить, что долгие годы замалчивалась некоторая политическая зависимость Московии от Крымского ханства. Между тем, проблема эта была решена только при Петре Первом.

> С 1686 г., после
> заключения между собой «вечного мира»,
> Россия и Речь Посполитая одновременно
> прекратили выплату поминков крымскому
> хану. Документальное оформление их
> отмены произошло также практически
> одновременно: упразднение крымских
> поминков с Речи Посполитой было
> закреплено Карловицким мирным
> договором 1699 г., с России –
> Константинопольским мирным
> договором 1700 г.
> [Ссылка](http://daumantas.diary.ru/p194056036.htm?oam)

Comment: Вы не точны @Дерзкий Grantum . Поселок Инкерман (бывший Белокаменск), в пригороде Севастополя , ни в каких пещерах никогда не размещался . На его территории есть Инкерманский Свято-Клементовский пещерный монастырь основанный на рубеже I-II веков н.э. святым Клементом . Это прорубленная в скале штольня-коридор и зал для богослужения . И ещё вовне несколько отдельных скальных келий . Построен римскими каторжниками , иудеохристианами . Размеры монастыря более , чем скромны , чтобы он мог называться городом . При советской власти был закрыт , в постсоветские времена восстановлен.

Comment: «Существует мнение, что в подражание Каракоруму московский белокаменный Кремль называли - Ак-Корум» — у кого существует такое мнение?